# Linux - Unable to set Blender to correct PULSEAUDIO Device

Tags: rendering

Removed by the author.
Removed by the author.

Comment: Interesting.. I can reproduce this here on archlinux, but I have no idea what's going on. I did find [a similar sounding issue](https://developer.blender.org/T33840) which appears to have been overcome, but I didn't see much useful info there..

Comment: Maybe related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/60683/2843

Comment: I've looked at that before posting. The Built-In Audio Analog Stereo doesn't work for any of my applications in pavucontrol. ALl other applications (including other video editors like KDENLIVE, OpenShot) are all set to HDMI Audio Controller (HDMI 2) and the sound works fine.  Blender is the only one which it doesn't.

Comment: well , i have the same problem with blender 2.78,the device stays on HDMI , i cant select my usb audio althoug it appears on the options.
Anyway , it works with jack...

Answer (score 0):

it seems that Blender makes the choice of its default output, for me , with 2.69 its my usb-audio card, with 2.70 and above , HDMI audio.in all these cases , i cannot change the selection in pavu-control...too bad obliged to stick with the old version.